# how to attach posted data with url?

Tags: php, jquery, url

i make a php page in which i want to move previous page on button click,i want to attach post data with url and on previous page data shown in fields how i attach post data?here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery("#previous").click(function() {
window.location.href = "<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>";
});
});

</script>
<?
$data=($_POST);
?>
<input id="previous" type="button" class="button edit" name="submit_skip" value="Edit Message" />
<input type="submit" class="button email" name="submit_email" value="Send Message" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use back button as a submit button and create a html form with hidden fields to post/get the data:

```
<form name='previous' method='get' action='<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>'>
<?php 
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) 
{
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='$key' value='$value'>"; 
}
?>
</form>

<input id="previous" type="button" class="button edit" name="submit_skip" value="Edit Message" onclick='document.forms["previous"].submit();' />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`http_build_query`**](https://www.php.net/http_build_query), eg `http_build_query($_POST);` to include the current `$_POST`-data when redirecting.

```php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'?'.http_build_query($_POST);
```

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#previous").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "<? echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'?'.http_build_query($_POST);?>";
    });
});
```

will redirect to

`example.com?param1=value1&param2=value2` etc

This will of course fail if there is no `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` set.